How to Create an Admin Account in Laravel 11 Using Breeze?
I'm working on a project using Laravel 11, and I installed it via Breeze. I want to create an admin account that is separate from regular user accounts. My goal is to have role-based authentication where admins have different permissions compared to regular users.
I’ve searched for tutorials, but most of them are for older versions of Laravel or don't cover Breeze. Could someone guide me on the best way to implement this in Laravel 11?
Specifically, I'm looking for:

How to set up an admin role during user registration or manually assign it after the user is created.
How to restrict certain routes or areas of the application to only be accessible by admins.
Best practices for managing roles and permissions in Laravel 11 with Breeze.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
What I Tried:
I installed Laravel 11 using Laravel Breeze for authentication. I expected that I could easily create a separate admin account that has different permissions from regular users. I followed the Breeze setup and successfully created user authentication, but I'm unsure how to implement a system where admin accounts are separate and have distinct privileges from regular users.
I have reviewed the documentation, and I've seen tutorials on creating admin panels, but most of them are for older versions of Laravel or do not use Breeze. I tried modifying the User model to include an is_admin field, but I'm not certain how to apply this across the application or how to restrict certain routes to admin users only.
What I Expected:
I expected to find a straightforward way to create and manage admin accounts that are distinct from regular user accounts, including setting up middleware or guards that restrict access to specific parts of the application for admins only.

Use Authorization https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/authorization

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I just sorted this out myself. Laravel Breeze supports implementing roles and permissions in your application.
1. Add Role Column to Users Table
First, add a new column to your users table to store the user's role. You can use an enum column for this:
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->enum('role', ['user', 'admin'])->default('user');
});

2. Create Role Middleware
Next, create middleware to check the user's role and restrict access accordingly:
php artisan make:middleware RoleMiddleware

In the RoleMiddleware class, add logic to check the role:
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    if ($request->user()->role !== $role) {
        abort(403);
    }

    return $next($request);
}

Register the middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php:
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
];

3. Create Role-Based Routes and Views
Now you can create separate routes and views for each role. For example:
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('admin.dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'role:admin']);

Route::get('/user', function () {
    return view('user.dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'role:user']);

Create the corresponding views in resources/views/admin and resources/views/user.
4. Redirect Users to Appropriate Dashboard
In the LoginController, redirect users to their respective dashboards based on their role:
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->role === 'admin') {
        return redirect('/admin');
    } else {
        return redirect('/user');
    }
}

For more advanced role management, consider using a package like Spatie or Bouncer. Or upgrade to Jetstream from Breeze.

Where would this actually be added or created at?
